# Error Using Matlab to Update MS Access

Tags: matlab, ms-access

I'm trying to import data from a MS Access database from Matlab and I'm getting the following error:

Error using database/fetch (line 37)
[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] The query cannot
be completed. Either the size of the query result is larger
than the maximum size of a database (2 GB), or there is not
enough temporary storage space on the disk to store the
query result.

I have 4GB of RAM and 60GB of free hard drive space so I don't think it's a space problem. The database is 1022Mb.

Answer (score 0):

Are you by any chance asking for a huge amount of data?
A few nice outerjoins perhaps, or multiple combinations of tables?

My guess is that if this is causing the problem, you should just split the query up into a few pieces and it will work.